# How to display multiple images from the post on the homepage

Tags: posts

I have a wordpress question. 
Each post has multiple thumbnails, company logo and description. See the mockup: http://d.pr/i/19rBb

And on the homepage, I would like to display all the thumbnails minus the company logo. See the mockup: http://d.pr/i/zyRe

What's the best way to accomplish it? I would like to understand the concept more than the code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be how wordpress handle Featured Image in core. They just store the `attachment_id` in a post meta named `_thumbnail_id`.

You should do the same in your case. But instead of setting featured image(for which Wordpress has default functions), you need to create the attachments yourself. You can follow these steps -

1. Insert the image for 1st thumbnail and save the attachment id in your post meta( Say `first_thumbnail` or any other name that doesn't conflict with existing names like `_thumbnail_id` which is used by wordpress by default for storing the featured image.)
2. The same applies for other thumbnails and company logo.
3. Storing description is easier. Just save the text in a postmeta.
4. Now where you want to display these postmetas(or whether you want to display at all) is totally up to.

**Functions that you will need**

- [wp_insert_attachment()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment)
- [wp_get_attachment_url()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url)
- [wp_generate_attachment_metadata()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_generate_attachment_metadata)
- [update_post_meta()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta)
- [get_post_meta()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta)